# Intersection of all Sobolev spaces with negative order

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Call $H^{s}$ the usual $L^2$-based Sobolev spaces on, say, a closed manifold, for $s \in \mathbb R$. The intersection $\bigcap _{s<0} H^s $ contains $L^2$. Is this intersection *equal* to $L^2$?

Thank you.

Comment: prolly not.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $f \in \cap_{s < 0}H^s(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\hat f(t) = (1+t^2)^{-1/4}$. This function is not in $L^2$.

Comment: But is this intersection a Hilbert space?

Comment: I think the answer is no. But that's a new question.which you might post separately.